# Wordpress Plugin Active Function

Tags: php, wordpress, function, plugins, action

I want try to create process at my plugin.

I want to do :
I don't know to to create a code..

`is_plugin_active` will do action of function `loading_command()`

anybody understand?

Comment: If you're asking about running stuff one time when the plugin is first activated, that no longer exists. Alternatively, you can add some meta info and have the plugin check for it--if it already exists the one-time action has been run and doesn't need to run again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the best place to start learning how to write WordPress plugins:

http://codex.wordpress.org/Writing_a_Plugin